# How do browsers based on Chromium import passwords from Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, python, passwords, c

How do browsers based on chromium import passwords from Chrome?

Browsers like Vivaldi Brave, Edge, Opera, etc… all have feature to import passwords from Chrome, and some even have ability to import from Edge.

Not about CSV import, but they can directly import from login data file, with no prompts from antivirus software.

Everything online for decrypting Chrome passwords is outdated or detected to be a virus or something by AV.

What is the code these browsers use exactly?

Or is it that they get certified from every AV company to allow use of a prohibited code for fair purpose of importing passwords to another browser (which I don’t guess so).

*Expecting python/c/c++ code.*

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They use the same code that Chrome uses, because they are *literally the same program* at the core. (Chrome itself is based on Chromium, just like Brave or Edge are.)

AV software don't just blindly detect anything that reads the database – Chrome is of course allowed to read its own data – and since Edge is 95% Chrome, it doesn't look any different.

(I also suspect most AV software don't detect anything that reads the database, in general, but only specific patterns that "known" password-recovery tools use...)

Comment: To me going through cc and h files for understanding exact code on how to decrypt is hard. Chrome code is very big to understand completely and just getting a pie from it is too high, anyway, bye : )